# WiFi not working with Broadcom 43ba driver

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, network-interface, broadcom

I've installed Debian Jessie to dual-boot on a Macbook Pro 12,1. So far, I haven't been able to set up my WiFi drivers correctly. I've followed the instructions [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211) in this way:

1. **Found my chipset** using the table on the documentation above.

   > BCM43602  14e4:43ba
2. **Downloaded necessary `.bin` files** by cloning the [repository](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git)  and moving the files for my chipset (`brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin` and `brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin`) into `/etc/firmware/brcm`.

I haven't done the step that reads:

> For SDIO driver you need to copy the nvram for your system and place it in /lib/firmware/brcm.

The reason is because I don't think the computer would be using the SDIO driver, but rather the PCIE driver. *I'm not sure about this*. A secondary reason is that I could not find the nvram file in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` after `mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars`.

On rebooting, the driver appears **not** to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notes for the chip BCM43602 say:

> Supported in 3.17+.

You probably have an older kernel. Check by running:

```
uname -r
```

If this is the case, update your kernel to >= 3.17 and everything will work properly.

### Updating your kernel

You can update your kernel by adding jessie-backports to your sources list. Open up `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Save, then determine which kernel you want to install:

```
apt-cache -t jessie-backports search linux-image
```

Then, run the following, replacing VERSION with the kernel version.

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-VERSION
```